# Make cell mandatory in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried this code for creating mandatory fields but the problem is it is showing the error message before going to the cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim I, J As Integer
        For I = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(I, "C").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Business Type Value", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
        End If
        'If Cells(I, "D").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter Customer Account Code", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "E").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter Transport Mode Value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "F").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter Incoterm Value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "K").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter From date Value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "L").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter To date Value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "K").Value > Cells(I, "L").Value Then
        'MsgBox "To date value should greater than From value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "N").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter Origin Country Code Value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "O").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter Point of Origin Location Code Value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "R").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter Port of Loading Code Value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "S").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter Origin Clearance Location Value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "T").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter Destination Clearance Location Value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        'If Cells(I, "U").Value = "" Then
        'MsgBox "Please Enter Port of Discharge Code Value", vbOKOnly
        'Exit Sub
        'End If
        If Cells(I, "Y").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Consignee Final Destination Location Code Value", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
        End If
        If Cells(I, "Z").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Destination Country Code Value", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
        End If
        If Cells(I, "AF").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Active status Value", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
        End If
        If Cells(I, "AH").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Carrier Allocation Number Value", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
        End If
        If Cells(I, "AI").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter  Carrier Allocation Valid From Date Value", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
        End If
        If Cells(I, "AJ").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter Carrier Nomination Sequence Number Value", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
        End If
        Next I
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This code

- tracks A1:A10 to see if any cells are changed
- then looks to see if the corresponding cell in row Y is empty

  - if empty a message is returned and the cell in A1:A10 that was changed is then blanked out

*code*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Intersect(Target, [a1:a10])
'exit if no cells in A1:A10 are changed
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'turn off events to avoid code retriggering itself
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each rng2 In rng1
    If Cells(rng2.Row, "Y") = vbNullString Then
       MsgBox "Please Enter Consignee Final Destination Location Code Value, your entry will be deleted", vbOKOnly
       rng2.Value = vbNullString
    End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be:

1. In your Worksheet_SelectionChange make all cells which do not pass your checks red. All who pass your checks green. You can do this with the following code. Do not produce any error messages in this procedure.

`Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red`

`Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'green`

2. Do only allow saving the workbook if all your checks are passed. Therefore you can use the proceudre I have provided you in the other answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think the event you are using may cause your problem.

You could implement mandatory fields with the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event. This will get fired, as soon as the user tries to save the excel file. Now you check all your fields which you define as mandatory and display the respective "error message".

When you set `Cancel = True` you can abort the saving process wich then really forces the user to add something in the required fields.

In the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event you can paste in all your checks you have already implemented.

More details on the `Workbook_BeforeSave` can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff840057.aspx

Here you can find more info on how to implement the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event:http://www.positivevision.biz/blog/bid/153139/Excel-Tips-and-Tricks-Mandatory-Cell-Input

Comment: after changing it to Workbook_BeforeSave event. the validatios are not wrking.

Comment: please someday help me out

Comment: My first guess: You need to put the code into `This Workbook` not into the code for the sheet. However, you need to be **more detailed** with your post so we can help you.

Comment: i want to validate the cell as soon as the cursor moves to the next cell

Comment: there's no event which gets fired *after* a cell is changed. Only when you select the cell. However, the solution I provided you does implement the mandatory fields accordning to your question. Why dont you implement it like that?

Comment: as in the excel sheet i need to poplulate some 20000 records at a time, so by doing that during save how i can handle that much errors at a time

Comment: Create a string, and per mandatory cell which is missing add the cell name ("A1") to that tring. At the end you can output in one error message which cells have to be filled in.

Comment: is there any way to make a cell mandatory using data validation or any other feature of excel other than writing code  in vb

Comment: No not that I am ware of. If this helped you please up vote my answers and consider accepting one.

Comment: @blckbird *there's no event which gets fired after a cell is changed* - this is exactly what the Change event does.

Comment: Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim oldTarget  As Range

Set oldTarget = Target
If oldTarget.Address = "$B$1" Then
If Range("A1").Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Hi"
End If
End If
End Sub

i have used this for making cell mandatory, and this is wrking well for a cell, but now i want to use them for the whole column not only for A1 and A2